# Is a $3\times 3$ Matrix with 2 Eigenvalues diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have a $3\times 3$ Matrix polynomial which I computed the characteristic polynomial to be 
$x^3 - 2x^2 + x = x(x-1)^2$. This would give us Eigenvalues 0,1.

Seeing how there are 2 eigenvalues and $n = 3$ for this matrix. This would usually mean this matrix cannot be diagonalizable. However, I'm wondering if the multiplicity of 2 affects our eigenvalues?

Comment: The eigenvalues are 0,1,1. The algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda=1$ is 2, while it's geometric multiplicity is 1 (because you claimed there are 2 eigenvectors).

Comment: Algebraic multiplicity does not "affect" diagonalizability. It might be a symptom of non-diagonalizability, but per se for all $n$ and for any non-squarefree monic polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ there are $(n\times n)$ diagonalizable matrices with characteristic polynomial $(-1)^np$ and $(n\times n)$ non-diagonalizable matrices with characteristic polynomial $(-1)^np$.

Comment: Sorry I might have mistaken something. Wouldn't the eigenvalues 1,1 yield the same eigenvectors? Since for λ = 1, you would plug 1 into the matrix and row reduce to find the eigenvectors.

Comment: The repeated eigenvalues give the same **eigenspace**, but you may be able to find enough linearly independent eigenvectors to make things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may or may not be diagonalizable.

An example of such a matrix that is diagonalizable is
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$

An example of such a matrix that is **not** diagonalizable is
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$

(I'll leave it to you to establish that the first matrix is diagonalizable and the second one is not)

In short, the information you have is insufficient to determine whether the matrix is diagonalizable or not.

---

From comments, the matrix in question is
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
-2& 2 & 1\\
-4&4 & 2\\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$
If you check the nullity of $A-I$ (what you need to find the eigenvectors corresponding to $1$), you will find that the rank of $A-I$ is $2$ and the nullity is $1$. That means the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=1$ is $1$, strictly less than its algebraic multiplicity, so the matrix in question is **not** diagonalizable.

Comment: Hi, I'm not very good at using the matrix formatter, so I hope an image will do https://imgur.com/a/cKMyoLE . From what I understand, A matrix is diagonalizable if number of eigenvectors is equal to the dimensions of the matrix. From my characteristic polynomials, my eigenvalues are 0,1,1. However, wouldn't both the eigenvalues 1 yield the same eigenvector for both eigenvalues, thus giving me 2 eigenvectors.

Comment: @MioChibana: What you describe is a **sufficient** condition: if an $n\times n$ matrix has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, **then** it is diagonalizable. But if it has fewer than $n$ distinct eigenvalues, that just means that this condition is not met, not that the conclusion is not met. "If I fall into the pool, then I will get wet" is a true statement. But that does not mean that if I don't fall into the pool then I'm going to be dry: I could get caught in a rainstorm, after all.

Comment: Your image is a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to show this as the image of the matrix https://imgur.com/a/9Wknd6F

Comment: And, again, no; the eigenvalue $1$ yields the same set of eigenvectors (the same eigenspace). Is the identity matrix diagonalizable? Yes. Even though it has only one eigenvalue.

Comment: What you need to do is check is the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda =1$ is equal to its algebraic multiplicity. The algebraic multiplicity is the multiplicity as a root of the characteristic polynomial (in this case, $2$). The geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the eigenspace $N(A-I)$. A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its characteristic polynomial splits **and** the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of each eigenvalue are equal. The case of $n$ distinct eigenvalues can be proven to satisfy the latter condition, which is why it yields diagonalizability.